# How we convert UIButton in triangle Shape in iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to create a `UIButton` in triangle shape. I have a triangle shape image and I set this image on the button and when we click on the button then the click scope of the button is increase. Other button is effect when click on triangle button.

Comment: UIButton ignores touch if you touch it where there's no image alpha. So if the triangle image you have set for your button has a transparent background then it will not respond when you click outside of the triangle image area.

Comment: Image is transparent background. Button click scope same